# Inner joined query with multiple where clauses linked to multiple controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting a Runtime error 2424 message when building a string containing my SQL `UPDATE` statement.  Access complains that one of the controls or tables is unrecognised.  My instinct tells me that I have issues with my parentheses or the quotation marks.

```
st_sql = "UPDATE tblCompetency02 INNER JOIN (tblCompetency05 INNER JOIN tblCompetency03 ON tblCompetency05.CompetencyID = tblCompetency03.ID) ON tblCompetency02.ID = tblCompetency03.HighLevelObjective SET tblCompetency05.Checklist = 'YES' WHERE [tblCompetency03].[RoleModelLevel]='self' and [tblCompetency05].[TeamID]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.TeamID & " and [tblCompetency03].[Order]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.txtOrder & " and [tblCompetency02].[ID]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.HLO & ""
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

`Me.TeamID`, `Me.txtOrder`, and `Me.HLO` are text box controls.

Comment: Does the error occur on the `st_sql =` line or the `Application.DoCmd` line?

Comment: Thanks.  What are `Me.TeamID`, `Me.Order`, and `Me.HLO`?  Are they text boxes or something else?

Comment: They are text box controls which pull values from the underlying query which feeds the form. All numerical values

Comment: Good.  Rename your `Order` text box to `txtOrder`.  Then use `Me.txtOrder` when you build the `UPDATE` statement.  What happens when you run the code after those changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result

Comment: Hmm.  Go into debug mode when you hit that error.  In the Immediate window, paste in `Debug.Print Me.TeamID` and press enter.  Do the same for  `Debug.Print Me.txtOrder` and `Debug.Print Me.HLO`.  Which one of them does Access complain about?

Comment: Hans, it doesn't seem to like any of them

Comment: Again in debug mode, in the Immedate window, paste this as one line and press Enter: `for each ctl in me.Controls : ? ctl.name, typename(ctl) : next`  That should show you the name and type of every control on the current form.  Are those 3 controls included in that output?

Comment: those three controls exist as text boxes

Comment: But Access doesn't find them when you're building the *st_sql* string.  I don't understand how that is possible.  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: We are definately on the right track because i ran the query without the three controls at the end and all works fine.  I feel like there is something that isnt working with the parenthesis or the quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
st_sql = "UPDATE tblCompetency02 INNER JOIN (tblCompetency05 INNER JOIN tblCompetency03 ON tblCompetency05.CompetencyID = tblCompetency03.ID) ON tblCompetency02.ID = tblCompetency03.HighLevelObjective SET tblCompetency05.Checklist = 'YES' WHERE [tblCompetency03].[RoleModelLevel]='self' and [tblCompetency05].[TeamID]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.TeamID & " and [tblCompetency03].[Order]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.txtOrder & " and [tblCompetency02].[ID]= " & Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.HLO & ""
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```